# Mystery driver I can't identify

Tags: speakers, compression

I have a mystery compression driver (tweeter)

Hi there,

I'm new to working with compression drivers and could use some advice. I have a few questions:

How do I identify the make and model of a compression driver?
Any tips on choosing the right horn for it?
How can I determine the power handling capacity in watts?
Is it worth experimenting with it?
I appreciate any insights !

photos of the driver :

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
if this can be any help its the driver from france police siren

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be more about audio equipment than musical practice, and instrument/gear identification questions have typically been treated as off-topic.

Comment: The quality control sticker says Mercura. They make speakers...

Comment: didnt seem to find "mercura" audio manifacturer

Comment: First hit on google - https://standby-mercura.fr/product-category/sirenes-et-haut-parleurs/